# How can I collaborate with multiple developers?

Tags: database, importing-exporting, version-control

I am developing a website on Drupal with 2 other developers. What would be the best way to collaborate? We plan to work on different git branches and there will be a dev and production branch as well. How can we keep in sync with the database structure without overwriting each others' work?

Comment: Everything important is in configuration. Use version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with Drupal's configuration management system. Have a read of https://www.drupal.org/docs/configuration-management to get started

Essentially any site changes apart from content can be stored in .yml files which you can import/export on each environment (storing them in GIT)

I wouldn't recommend trying to synchronize content and this is better done manually on your dev/stage/prod environment. But if you really wanted to there is the default content module which allows for content to go into .yml files too https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content

Comment: Wouldn't it cause merge conflicts? If I and a new content type and other developer adds new custom block type. When he pushes a commit and I import the config, won't it cause merge conflicts/overwrite my changes?

Comment: No because each config e.g. content type, field, block.... are in separate .yml files. So if everything is new it's unlikely to cause any conflicts as you'll be adding/editing separate .yml files. The only time you'd have an issue is if you both edited exactly the same thing like the label for a field. In that case, you'd get a GIT conflict but you'd just have to sort those out like any code conflict

Comment: This is the correct answer. Merge conflicts are a part of life for developers but speaking from experience they are uncommon in configuration synchronization as long as you import the configuration on HEAD before working. The use-case in the question is the reason Drupal's configuration synchronization system exists.

Comment: Great. Thanks for explanation.